# Not able to get json request in express delete with restangular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, restangular

Here is the restangular code that i am using to delete the object

```
$scope.delO = (id){
  Restangular
    .one("footer",id)
    .get()
    .then((ob)=>{
      ob.remove();
    }
    .catch....
}
```

The request is being sent properly as i validated in my browser. Here is the express code

```
route.delete("/",(req,res,next)=>{
  console.log(req.body);
  helper['del'](req.body._id)
    .then(()=>{
      res.status(200).end();
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      res.status(400).json({err:err.message});
    });
});
```

The `req.body` comes as empty. According to [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986569/how-to-get-parameter-for-delete-request-in-express-node-js) I see it should be in the parameter.

Can someone please explain where am i going wrong ?

### Edit

Just to remove some confusion here is a screenshot from browser

[image: Network screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be no data post in `DELETE` verb. So in order for the above code to work, i had to modify it as

```
  $scope.delExisting = ()=>{
    console.log($scope.form._id);
    Restangular
      .one("footer/"+$scope.form._id)
      .remove()
      .then((data)=>{
        $scope.list();
      })
      .catch((err)=>{
        console.log("Error");
      });
  }
```

And on express taking on the `id` of the element to be deleted from the `uri` instead.