# How do I get pull working correctly with mongoose and mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to pull an object from an array inside of a Model. However I cannot get it to work properly. I have checked my query params so i know that they are outputting the correct values. Any help would be appreciated!!

Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const collectionSchema = new Schema({
    type: String,
    name: String,
    id: String,
    gamesCollected: [
        {
            id: Number,
            name: String,
            summary: String,
            first_release_date: Number,
            screenshots: [
                {
                    url: String,
                    couldinary_id: String,
                    width: Number,
                    height: Number
                }
            ],
            cover: {
                url: String,
                couldinary_id: String,
                width: Number,
                height: Number
            },
            platfroms: [
                Number
            ]

        }
    ]
});

mongoose.model('collection', collectionSchema);
```

Route:

```
router.delete('/delete_game', (req, res) => {
    Collection.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.query.collectionID}, {$pull: 
    {gamesCollected: {_id: req.query.id}}});
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: Hmmn. `id: Number,` is in the schema for those sub-documents. But "mongoose" aliases `_id` and `id` and has an `ObjectId` type. You probably should be getting a "cast error" or something similar. Same goes for the `_id` in the query conditions where again you have `id: String`. You should show the actual document you expect to be effected since the update is likely not matching any document at all. Also `findOneAndUpdate()` is an "async" method and you are not waiting on it to resolve, but that's a different and new issue.

Comment: Got bored and tested this so mongoose is storing "both" `id` and `_id` now ( not sure when that changed ) but you probably do mean `{$pull: { gamesCollected: { id: req.query.id } } }` and not `_id`. Same is likely for the `_id` in the query condition as well. But as already stated, "show the document and query parameters being sent" if you think you actually do mean the `_id` values instead.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace req.query with req.body

```
router.delete('/delete_game', (req, res) => {
    Collection.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body.collectionID}, {$pull: 
    {gamesCollected: {_id: req.body.id}}});
    res.end();
});
```

Once refer the similar question [How to get parameter for delete request in express node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986569/how-to-get-parameter-for-delete-request-in-express-node-js)